# Ignorar a primeira linha

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estou usando o seguinte comando pra organizar um arquivo:

```
sort -u arquivo.csv -o arquivo.csv
```

Mas preciso ignorar a primeira linha dele, no caso o cabeçalho.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Leitura e escrita no mesmo arquivo simultaneamente não costuma dar certo (apesar de nunca ter lido a documentação do `sort` para ter certeza para esse comando). No caso, você desejaria separar o cabeçalho e ordenar o resto do arquivo?

Comment: Exatamente isso!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o comando `tail` com a opção `-n`:

```
tail -n +2 arquivo.csv
```

No caso, `-n +2` vai exibir somente da segunda linha em diante (você pode mudar o número para qualquer valor que precisar).
O sinal de `+` também é importante, pois se você escrever apenas `-n 2`, ele vai mostrar as duas últimas linhas.

Depois você pode passar o resultado diretamente para o `sort`:

```
tail -n +2 arquivo.csv | sort -u > arquivo_ordenado.csv
```

Além disso, recomendo salvar a saída em outro arquivo (como fiz acima), já que ler e escrever no mesmo arquivo não costuma dar muito certo (por experiência própria, dependendo do comando, o arquivo é sobrescrito e/ou truncado e você acaba perdendo os dados - não sei como o `sort` trata isso, mas eu prefiro não arriscar).

<sup>A [resposta do Lacobus](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/304857) responde a essa dúvida específica sobre o `sort`.</sup>

---

#### Manter o cabeçalho

Como bem lembrado nos comentários, com o comando acima, a primeira linha (cabeçalho) é perdida. Caso você precise dela no arquivo final, uma maneira de fazer é quebrar em dois comandos.

Primeiro guarde a primeira linha no arquivo final, com o comando `head`:

```
head -1 arquivo.csv > arquivo_ordenado.csv
```

O parâmetro `-1` diz para pegar somente a primeira linha. Depois faça o `tail` e `sort`, e adicione o resultado no arquivo:

```
tail -n +2 arquivo.csv | sort -u >> arquivo_ordenado.csv
```

Repare que agora estou usando `>>`, que adiciona as informações no final do arquivo. Se eu usar somente `>`, o conteúdo do arquivo é sobrescrito e o cabeçalho será perdido.

Comment: Só faltou guardar o cabeçalho para pô-lo no arquivo ordenado.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado De fato, quando li *"preciso ignorar a primeira linha"*, entendi que ela não precisava estar no arquivo final, mas faz sentido ela estar. Atualizei a resposta, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o utilitário `tail` para ignorar a primeira linha do arquivo de entrada antes de redirecionar sua saída para `sort`, veja só:

```
$ tail -n +2 arquivo.csv | sort -u -o arquivo.csv
```

Segundo a documentação do utilitário `sort`, o processo de ordenação é feito em memória, antes da abertura/escrita do arquivo de saída (especificado com a opção `-o`), isso garante uma ordenação *in place* do arquivo de forma segura.

Repare que a primeira linha do arquivo é *destruída* com a execução desse comando.

Referência: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29697/does-sort-support-sorting-a-file-in-place-like-sed-in-place

Comment: Bom saber que o `-o outfile` é lazy. Pensando bem, toda ordenação exige isso, pois só posso saber quem é o primeiro elemento depois de terminar a operação em todo o conjunto de dados